# Unable to call getMapAsync function using Kotlin Android Extensions

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

My layout file is -

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.map.com.mapproject.MapsActivity" />
```

i am calling  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this) from my MapActivity but the function is not available for this variable. But using findViewById as old way is working fine.

```
 val mapFragment = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
```

Now i want to know how to directly call getMapAsync function from id field as Kotlin Android extensions are doing for other views in my layout.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `Activity` then you can use this in `onCreateView()` for `OnMapReadyCallback`

```
val mapFragment: SupportMapFragment? = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
```

Here is my XML for same

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

When using synthetic properties the variable is cast to the type of the View that is in the layout. In this instance the type is a `Fragment`.

If you still want to use the synthetic property you will need to cast it to `SupportMapFragment` before calling `getMapAsync()`. You could use something like:

```
(mapFragment as? SupportMapFragment)?.getMapAsync(this)
```

or assign it to another variable first

```
val supportMapFragment = mapFragment as? SupportMapFragment
supportMapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
```

Comment: The cast can never succeed

Comment: Bit late seeing this reply. But, I don't see why this cast will never succeed? I've tested it out and it does return the SupportMapFragment.